# How to say, I/you need [a] better [noun]?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

> もっと良いインターネットを要ります。
>
> もっと良いインターネットが必要です。

The scenario being that either I have a crappy connection or a friend of mine has a crappy connection. Is either of those examples too literal for `I need better internet` or `You need better internet`? Is there something more idiomatic?

Answer (score 2):

Your second sentence is good, but your first is incorrect for using a 「を」.　It needs to be 「が」 just like in your second.

You could also say:

「もっと良いインターネットがほしいです。」

Your second sentence, while 100% correct, sounds a little bit stiff if you are speaking instead of writing.  It just sounds "translated" from another language.

Using 「～～がほしいです」 or 「～～がほしいと思{おも}っています」 would sound more natural in informal oral communication.

Comment: If I found out you used 56k and wanted to express `You need better internet`, would your answer still work? In fact, I'll update my question.